# Number of lattice points in a given triangle

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, lattices, euclidean-lattices

Given a triangle with real coordinates, does anybody know how to find the number of lattice points contained within it? What if the points are only rational? I know Pick's formula can be used for the integral case, that does not interest me.

Comment: What kind of a solution are you looking for and why? An explicit formula? Some kind of estimates or asymptotic behaviour? (I assume you mean that the triangle is in the plane $\mathbb R^2$ and the lattice is $\mathbb Z^2$. You might want to specify this in your question.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I am wondering how explicit a formula can be given that this problem fundamentally involves a kind of Diophantine analysis and therefore might not be solvable. And yes, I meant the plane and integer lattice in my question.

Comment: There will be approaches under the different headings of the Poisson summation formula, and integer programming. Why should we expect an interesting answer in general?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116689/counting-integral-lattice-points-in-a-triangle-that-may-not-have-integer-coordin

Comment: @IgorRivin The answers in that question weren't closed-form.

Comment: If that question didn't get any closed-form answers, and your question is even harder, then maybe you are optimistic if you expect a closed-form answer to your question.